# Help identifying connector with screw housing (RG...?)

Tags: connector, identification

I presume this should be a simple ID for someone who knows. I am interested in the general family of connector (e.g. RGxx). It's not something I ever use but as I have a box of them I could do with knowing what they are.

[image]
[image]

Comment: RGxxx is used for cable families, not connectors.

Comment: What could those four-way connectors have been used for?

Comment: @MikeWaters they might be one-third power splitters – but I'd have my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly called PL-259 or "UHF connector"; it's [not really](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/pl-259-so-239-vs-n-type-vs-bnc-which-is-best-connector-to-use-when/13062#13062) suited for UHF, though, by modern standards, imho.

> It's not something I ever use but as I have a box of them I could do with knowing what they are.

Those used to be used in (non-military, non-measurement) radio equipment for HF bands. They're not really great RF connectors, so basically only legacy devices still use them. Unless you have a few of these, it's probably not worth hanging on to them. ebay might be your friend, helping you get rid of them, or some ham radio forums.

They might be nice for low- to medium power audio wiring, but they'd be totally nonstandard for such applications.

Comment: UHF connectors are commonly used on VHF radios (150 MHz area)

Comment: @PeterBennett yep. See what the linked answer says :)

Comment: Hi Marcus, I forget the details, but I saw some lab measurements (loss and impedance bumps) which indicated that they were usable at 220 MHz for most amateur purposes. But that was pushing the upper usable limit! Above that, *forget it*. :-) I used some UHF connectors at about 300 watts on 2M, and can testify to that.